# Update Property of Every Object in Array in React JS Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects. I want to update one property of every object in the array inside a function.

I declare a function outside `render`:

```
const computePiePercentages = function(pieChartData, remainingBudget){
  var denominator = 1600;
  if(remainingBudget > 0){
    denominator = 1600 - remainingBudget
  }


  return pieChartData.map((val, j) => {
    val.y = Number((val.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100

  });


  };
```

I am still very new to react - I know that `pieChartData.map((val, j)` allows me to loop through the objects in my array. I thought by `return pieChartData.map((val, j)` I would be returning the updated array. However, that doesn't appear to be the case. I am currently getting `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` for scale.js (I dont even know this file)

I call the function here:

```
render() {

    const { data, remainingBudget, pieChartData, outOfBudget, answeredQuestions } = this.state;

    const questions = data.questions;
    return (
      <div>
          {answeredQuestions == 1 &&
          <div>
            <VictoryPie
              colorScale = "blue"
              data = {computePiePercentages(pieChartData, remainingBudget)}
              //data = {this.state.pieChartData}
              labels= {d => `${d.x}: ${d.y}%`}
              style={{ parent: { maxWidth: '50%' } }}
              />
            {outOfBudget.length > 0 &&
              <div>
              <Table>
                <th>Out of Budget</th>
                < BrokeBudget
                  outOfBudget={outOfBudget}
                  />
              </Table>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, all answers (up to now) mutates the state objects directly, which is forbidden in React.

Comment: What is a safe solution?

Comment: Based on [_Updating an Item in an Array_](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array), you should return a new object when mapping: `pieChartData.map((val, j) => ({ ...val, y: /* computation here */ }))`

Comment: but `y` is a property of `val` - doesn't the syntax  `{ ...val, y: /* computation here */ }` suggest `y` is another element in an array ?

Comment: `...val` spreads properties of `val` into our new object, then we override the `y` property in our new object with the computation: `Number((val.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100`

Answer (score 1):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. So you must return a value from callback function for the new array, as it doesn't modify existing array.

map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

So below should fix the issue for you :

```js
const computePiePercentages = function(pieChartData, remainingBudget){
  var denominator = 1600;
  if(remainingBudget > 0){
    denominator = 1600 - remainingBudget
  }


  return pieChartData.map((val, j) => {
    let newVal = Object.assign({}, val);
    newVal.y = Number((newVal.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100
    return newVal;
  });


  };
```

Comment: `val.y = /**/` does modify objects within that new array, which are shared references in the previous state.

Comment: I gave one in the question's comments, feel free to use it!

Comment: I have used Object.assign

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a return value in your `map` function:

```
return pieChartData.map(val => {
  val.y = Number((val.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100
  return val;
});
```

Also, consider just storing this modified version of pieChartData, so the value doesn't need to be computed each time the component is rendered.