# Is Javascript Map Function Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am updating properties of a state element inside of `map`

```
  computePiePercentages(){
    var denominator = 1600
    if (this.state.total < 1600){
      denominator = this.state.total
    }

    return this.state.pieChartData.map((item, index) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        y: Number((item.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100
      }
    })
}
```

However, when I display the chart using `pieChartData` - `y` hasn't updated. I checked my math to make sure I am setting to the correct value inside `computePiePercentages`

Is the `map` function asynchronous like `setState`? How can I make sure to wait for the update to happen before I display my results?

Here is the rest of relevant code:

```
class Budget extends React.Component {
computePiePercentages(){
    var denominator = 1600
    if (this.state.total < 1600){
      denominator = this.state.total
    }

    return this.state.pieChartData.map((item, index) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        y: Number((item.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100
      }
    })
}


    computeTotals(){
    var runningTotal = 0
    var pieArray = []
    var beyondBudget = {}

    Object.entries(this.state.data.selectedQuestions).map((element, j)  => {
      console.log("hi here")
      console.log(element)
    //return selectedQuestions.map((val, j) => {
      const value = Object.values(element[1])[0]
      const name = element[0]

      runningTotal += value
      if(runningTotal <= 1600){
        let pieSlice =
             {
               x: name,
               y: value
             };
        pieArray = pieArray.concat(pieSlice)

      }
      else {

            if (Object.keys(beyondBudget).length == 0) {
                beyondBudget[name] = {};
                beyondBudget[name] = runningTotal - 1600;
                let pieSlice =
                     {
                       x: name,
                       y: value - (beyondBudget[name])
                     };
                pieArray = pieArray.concat(pieSlice)
            }
            if (!beyondBudget[name]) {
                beyondBudget[name] = {};
            }
            if (Object.keys(beyondBudget).length > 1) {
                beyondBudget[name] = value;
            }

        }
    });

    this.setState({
      pieChartData: pieArray,
      total: runningTotal,
      beyondBudget: beyondBudget,
    }, () => {
      this.computePiePercentages();
    });

}


  render() {
      const {
          data,
          pieChartData,
          beyondBudget,
          showResults,
          total
      } = this.state;
      const questions = data.questions;
      return (
          <div>
              {questions.map((q, i) => (
                  <UL key={i}>
                      <li>
                          <h4>{q.text}</h4>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <Options
                              state={this.state}
                              q={q}
                              i={i}
                              handler={this.handleInputChange}
                          />
                      </li>
                  </UL>
              ))}
              <button onClick={(event) => {
                this.computeTotals();
                this._showResults(true);
              }}>Click</button>
              {console.log(this.state.showResults)}
                {this.state.showResults &&
                  (<div>
                        <VictoryPie
                            colorScale="blue"
                            data={pieChartData}
                            labels={d => `${d.x}: ${d.y}%`}
                            style={{ parent: { maxWidth: '50%' } }}
                        />

                        {Object.keys(beyondBudget).length > 0 && (
                            <div>
                                <Table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Out of Budget</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <BrokeBudget
                                            beyondBudget={beyondBudget}
                                        />
                                    </tbody>
                                </Table>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                  )
                }
          </div>
      );
  }
  }
```

Comment: The `map()`function is a [standard javascript array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not "React". And while _it_ is not asynchronous, `console.log` _most certainly_ is, so if you need it to log "what the code is when you trigger the console log", rather than "when console.log actually performs its log operation", make sure to snapshot whatever it is you're trying to log (e.g. `slice()` if it's an array, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` for data objects, etc). Breakpoints are useful here too: inspect before "future" code runs.

Comment: `Array.map` is definitely not asynchronous. But it will be much easier to find a problem if you provide only code that is related to a problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I need to delete the `console.log` from the function - what I'm stuck on is why `VictoryPie` data (supplied by `pieChartData`, which is updated in `computePiePercentages`) in render is not correct

Comment: Where is `computePiePercentages` called? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: inside `computeTotals` - sorry got nervous i had too much code

Comment: Right, so you call the function, which returns an object, but you're not doing anything with that return value.

Comment: I was using this [react reference](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) that i got from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615262/update-property-of-every-object-in-array-in-react-js-function?noredirect=1#comment101688867_57615262) so I thought this was how one updates an element in an array? And when that value is returned, `pieChartData` should be updated, which is used in `VictoryPie`

Comment: You never update the state, so it doesn't change. By passing it in the setState callback it runs after the state update and the returned value is discarded. Also, "sorry got nervous i had too much code" that is a sign that you do, in fact, have too much code. But the way to solve it isn't to remove code, it's to create a minimal and ideally runnable test case that shows the problem.

Comment: so instead of returning a value inside `computePiePercentages` I should do `setState`? If so, I'm so confused by the answers I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615262/update-property-of-every-object-in-array-in-react-js-function?noredirect=1#comment101688867_57615262)

Comment: @maddie if you want `this.state.pieChartData` to change, yes. Mapping over an array returns a *new* array, it doesn't change the old one in place. And React wouldn't let you anyway, so yeah call `setState`.

Comment: @maddie the answer on the other question is correct. You don't call `setState` *inside* the map function, you map over the array and call `setState` with the *result*: `this.setState({ pieChartData: this.pieChartData.map(someFn) });`

Comment: Console.log is synchronous but it only pasts the reference so if the object you log changes, so will the object within you console. Can you show us where you actually use computePiePercentages()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, an array's `.map()` function returns a new array without changing the old array. So `this.computePiePercentages()` as it currently stands, creates a new array based on `this.state.pieChartData` and returns that new array. This action does not change `this.state.pieChartData`.

You're calling `this.computePiePercentages()` from the callback function of `this.setState()`. This is just a function, it has no special properties other than that it's called when the `setState()` is done changing the state. So to update the state further inside `computePiePercentages()` you need to call `setState()` again.

There are two options:

1. Update the state in the callback function, using the return value of `this.computePiePercentages`:

```
this.setState({
  pieChartData: pieArray,
  total: runningTotal,
  beyondBudget: beyondBudget,
}, () => {
  this.setState({
    pieChartData: this.computePiePercentages()
  });
});
```

2. Update the state in `this.computePiePercentages`:

```
this.setState({
  pieChartData: this.state.pieChartData.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      y: Number((item.y / denominator).toFixed(1)) * 100
    }
  })
});
```